# Question | Jquery plugin creation problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Why isn't this working?
---HTML--------

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="j.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.createHello();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---JS---------j.js-------

```
(function($){  
 $.fn.createHello= function() {  
    $('body').append('<div id="hello">Hello world</div>');
    $('#hello').click(funciton(){
    alert("Hello you clicker");
    });
 };  
})(jQuery);
```

Any solutions, or better ways to do the same thing?

Comment: **WHAT ISN'T WORKING ABOUT IT?** Sorry for the outrage, but I'm so sick of "questions" that just post code and ask "why isn't this working"; what errors do you get, what behaviour do you get and what behaviour do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `click` to `delegate` since you are creating the hello element on the fly. Below is the updated code. Also function was misspelled,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Z3w9V/)**

```
 $.createHello = function() {  
    $('body').append('<div id="hello">Hello world</div>');
    $('body').delegate('#hello', 'click', function(){
        alert("Hello you clicker");
    });
 } 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.createHello();
});
```

Personally this is how I would write it:

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Z3w9V/1/)**

```
 $.fn.createHello = function() {  
    $(this).append('<div id="hello">Hello world</div>');
    $(this).delegate('#hello', 'click', function(){
        alert("Hello you clicker");
    });
 } 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').createHello();
});
```

This allows you to tie it to any element on the page and call `createHello()`

I also suggest checking out the [plugin authoring reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for some good tips.

Answer (score 1):

since you defined the plugin using `$.fn.myPlugin`, you have to select an element for the plugin to work on. If you wish for the plugin to work in the way that you are using it, define it with

```
$.myPlugin = function(){
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`createHello` plugin is appending a div with some content to the body element. In order to attach a click event you should select the element and the refer to it using `this` keyword inside the plugin code. Try something like this

Add this markup in your test page

```
<div id="hello">Click me</div>
```

JS

```
 $.fn.createHello= function() {  
    $('body').append('<div id="hello">Hello world</div>');
    this.click(funciton(){
       alert("Hello you clicker");
    });
 };  


$("#hello").createHello();
```